# Boto3 get latest prefix/sub folder

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

I would like get get latest S3 prefix based on last modified time or creation time. Not sure if there is elegant way to do this. What i get so far is:

```
s3 = boto3.client("s3")
response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket="bucket_name", Delimiter="/", Prefix="abc/")['CommonPrefixes']

for obj in response:
   print obj['Prefix']

"bucket_name/abc/20190420"
"bucket_name/abc/20190421"
"bucket_name/abc/20190422"
"bucket_name/abc/20190423"
```

Let's say on each day we create a prefix and keys under the folder, what's the best way to get the latest prefix which is "bucket_name/abc/20190423" in this case assuming today is 2019-04-23? Also, don't assume prefix name is always number or date we easily parse and sort, it can be random letters or words as well.

Are the prefixes from the response natively ordered based on some modified time or creation time? If not, what is the most elegant way to get the most recent prefix?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that by "latest prefix" you mean "the prefix on the object most recently created".

Please note that prefixes don't actually get *created*. Rather, they are simply a portion of the `Key` (filename) of an object.

Obtaining the most recently created object is relatively simple. You could use the AWS CLI:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket my-bucket --query 'sort_by(Contents, &LastModified)[-1].Key' --output text
```

You could then manipulate the output via shell scripting (go up until the last slash).

In Python, you could use:

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket')

# Get the key of the object with the highest LastModified date
latest_object = max(response['Contents'], key = lambda obj: obj['LastModified'])['Key']

# Print prefix of latest object
if '/' in latest_object:
    print(latest_object[:latest_object.rfind('/')]  )
```

Comment: Thanks, understood that there is not folder concept for s3 paths and the objects are key based at the actual key level. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how boto3 works, but you could do a simple comparison using the `split` and `max` functions.

```
def getDateValue(prefixString):
    return int(prefixString.split("/")[2])

s3 = boto3.client("s3")
response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket="bucket_name", Delimiter="/", Prefix="abc/")['CommonPrefixes']

latest = max(response, key=getDateValue)
```

The function `getDateValue` takes the prefix, splits it based on the "/" character, gets the third part (the date) and converts it into an integer. The `max` function applies that to each prefix and returns the one with the highest value (i.e. the latest date)

Comment: what if the prefix name does not have a pattern, it is random letters each day created instead of a datetime? I updated the question to mentioned a possibility for that.

Comment: This would not work in that case. It will only work on text like the ones in your example, in which the final portion of the prefix can be converted into an integer.